# Invalid Parameter Error in RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, hyperparameters

I'm trying to learn RandomizedSearchCV in machine learning.

The code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("heart-disease.csv")
data_shuffled = data.sample(frac = 1)
X = data_shuffled.drop("target", axis = 1)
y = data_shuffled["target"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

grid = {"n_estimators": [10, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 1200],
        "max_depth": [None, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30],
        "max_featuers": ["auto", "sqrt"],
        "min_samples_split": [2, 4, 6],
        "min_samples_leaf": [1, 2, 4]}

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs = -1)

rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rfc,
                          param_distributions=grid,
                          n_iter = 100,
                          cv = 5,
                          verbose = 1)
rscv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter max_featuers for estimator RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_leaf=2, min_samples_split=6,
                       n_estimators=1200, n_jobs=-1). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I checked the RandomForestClassifier library to see if I passed out a wrong hyperparameter name but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the definition of your parameter grid: it should be `max_features` instead of `max_featuers`.

```py
grid = {
    "n_estimators": [10, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 1200],
    "max_depth": [None, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30],
    "max_features": ["auto", "sqrt"],  # <-- change here
    "min_samples_split": [2, 4, 6],
    "min_samples_leaf": [1, 2, 4]
}
```